# PHP Mysql pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pivot-table

I am using the  Following code to return a purchase details.That displays the result like this

```
Name    Qty Value
Product1 30 1000
Product1 45 2000
Product2 20 1500
Product2 25 3000
```

How can sum up the pdt's quantity and value And display like this

```
Name    Qty Value
Product1 75 3000
Product2 45 4500
Total    120 7500
```

With Select Where clause.

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT pdtname,pack,qty,value FROM ist WHERE  chemistcode='3121' AND chemistcode='3020' AND companycode = $companycode");

echo "<table id=customers>
<tr>
<th>Product</th>
<th>Pack</th>
<th>Qunatity</th>
<th>Value</th>
</tr>";


        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
echo "<tr>";
echo"<td>" . $row['pdtname'] . "</td>";
echo"<td>" . $row['pack'] . "</td>";
echo"<td>" . $row['qty'] . "</td>";
echo"<td>" . $row['value'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Modify your database query to use aggregate functions like SUM() and a GROUP BY clause; then calculate the totals when you handle the lop to display the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get the result by using the aggregate function `sum()` and by using [`group by with rollup`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html):

```
select 
  coalesce(name, 'Total') Name, 
  sum(qty) qty,
  sum(value) value
from ist
group by name with rollup;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54759f/2). This gives the result:

```
|     NAME | QTY | VALUE |
| Product1 |  75 |  3000 |
| Product2 |  45 |  4500 |
|    Total | 120 |  7500 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name,sum(Qty),sum(value) from table2 
group by name
union
select 'total',sum(Qty),sum(value) from table2
```